# Tensorflow 1.5 unoptimized build for debugging: compilation fails

Tags: c++, debugging, tensorflow, gpu

Building as follows to perform debugging of Tensorflow 1.5 backend:

```
bazel build -c opt --config cuda -c dbg --strip=never //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package -s
```

Gives:

```
INFO: From Compiling tensorflow/contrib/nccl/kernels/nccl_manager.cc:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h(327): error: calling a __host__ function("std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator< ::tensorflow::NcclManager::NcclStream *> ::_Rb_tree_const_iterator") from a __device__ function("std::pair< ::std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator< ::tensorflow::NcclManager::NcclStream *> , bool> ::pair< ::std::_Rb_tree_iterator< ::tensorflow::NcclManager::NcclStream *>  &, bool &, (bool)1> ") is not allowed

/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h(327): error: identifier "std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator< ::tensorflow::NcclManager::NcclStream *> ::_Rb_tree_const_iterator" is undefined in device code

/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h(1009): error: calling a __host__ function("__builtin_clzl") from a __device__ function("std::__lg") is not allowed
```

I guess we can get such functions properly folded by adding some inlining flag, yet keeping no other optimizations?